# How to prove that a moving particle passes through every point at least once, in a bounded area?

Tags: probability, geometry

Consider a rectangle and a moving particle with infinite energy and constant speed in a rectangle. (Particles bounces from the edges) Does this particle pass through every point in this field at least once? Or does it follow a certain scheme that will eventually make it impossible for it to go to certain points, regardless of initial shot angle and rectangular dimensions? For example, imagine that a shot is fired perpendicular to any edge, in this case, it always moves on the same points.
Intuitively, there is a situation where it will pass through any point, but how can we model it or prove there is such a case?

Comment: HINT. http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Remus/lesson1.html

Comment: I assume the particle is reflected (bounces) on the sides... but you don't say it

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks a lot. Actually, I am a 3 cushion billiard player, and this is exactly where the question came from.

Comment: The particle moves with constant (finite) speed, and hence cannot pass through an (uncountably) infinitely many points within a finite amount of time.